# Mandrill api cannot find messages method

Tags: c#, api, email, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm install the Mandrill Nuget Package and just want to send test message.

but Visual Studio Cannot find **messages** method:

var result = await api.**Messages**.SendAsync(message);

```
var api = new MandrillApi("YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE");
var message = new MandrillMessage("from@example.com", "to@example.com",
                "hello mandrill!", "...how are you?");
var result = await api.Messages.SendAsync(message);
```

Here is a [Github Project](https://github.com/feinoujc/Mandrill.net)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the references and other plugin related to mandrill `api` from `nuget`and install again